# I get wrong results using sum() clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to get total number of sent e-mails and mails. The problem is, I get only one count, not total. Could you tell me what's wrong with my Summary?

This is shortened version of my code:

```
with 
Customers1 as(          

SELECT   
count(1) as Result1

from table.documents d1, table.contracts c1
where d1.customerid = c1.customerid
and d1.documentid = c1.documentid 
and d1.type = 1  /* Sent by e-mail */
)  
,

Customers2 as(            
SELECT   
count(1) as Result2     
  
from table.documents d2, table.contracts c2
where d2.customerid = c2.customerid
and d2.documentid = c2.documentid 
and d2.type = 2  /* Sent by mail */
)
,

Summary as(
select
sum(Result1),
sum(Result2) as Total

from 
Customers1,
Customers2
)          
         
select 
Result1,
Result2,
Total

from 
Customers1,
Customers2,
Summary
```

Now Total is 700 instead of 3200:

```
Result1     Result2     Total
2500        700             700
```

Comment: Just a typo. summary query should be `sum(result1) + sum(Result2) as Total`

Comment: While this solves the problem, the query is still a monster query with 4 SELECTs for a simple task which can be solved easily with a single SELECT (see @Rapp's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77679699/880990) below)

Comment: Yes, @DRapp's answer was excellent and I'll try that.

Answer (score 3):

Your query could be simplified even further in one such as

```
SELECT
      sum( case when d1.type = 1 then 1 else 0 end ) TotalEmail,
      sum( case when d1.type = 2 then 1 else 0 end ) Mail,
      count(*) TotalSent
   from
      table.documents d1
         join table.contracts c1
            on d1.customerid = c1.customerid
            and d1.documentid = c1.documentid 
   where
      d1.type in ( 1, 2 )
```

Comment: Thank you for this tip. The shorter the code is, the better. Will definitely try this. I need to get better at making my code shorter.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to change the select block from

```
select
sum(Result1),
sum(Result2) as Total
```

to

```
select
sum(Result1) + sum(Result2) as Total.
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, Customer1 and 2 have only 1 record each. If correct, you could simplify this way:

```
with 
Customers1 as(          

SELECT   
count(1) as Result1

from table.documents d1, table.contracts c1
where d1.customerid = c1.customerid
and d1.documentid = c1.documentid 
and d1.type = 1  /* Sent by e-mail */
)  
,

Customers2 as(            
SELECT   
count(1) as Result2     
  
from table.documents d2, table.contracts c2
where d2.customerid = c2.customerid
and d2.documentid = c2.documentid 
and d2.type = 2  /* Sent by mail */
)
    
         
select 
Result1,
Result2,
Result1 + Result2 as Total

from 
Customers1, Customers2
```